# recursive tracing output sum of series

Tags: c++, recursion

Why is this recursive method not giving me the answer of 2.2833?

```
   double m(int i)
   {
       if (i == 1)
        return 1;
      else
        return (1/i) + m(i -1);
   }

   int main()
   {
        double value=m(5);
        cout << value << endl;

        return 0;
   }
```

The answer i get is 1?

Answer (score 1):

Because 1/1 is 1 and 1/2 = 0 (1/3 = 0 ....)

So we need to do `1.0/(double) i`

Then 1.0 / 2.0 = 0.5

```
#include <iostream>

double m(int i)
   {
       if (i == 1)
        return 1;
      else
        return (1.0/(double) i) + m(i -1);
   }

int main(int,char**) {
    double value=m(5);
    std::cout << value << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I explicity type casted it and now am getting the correct output thank you

Comment: @user2809437 Yup, `1.0` is double, `1.0f` is a float, `1` is an int, you should look into implicit casts for fundamental types. Remember to upvote and accept the answer :)